# Retrieving selected row Images from database SQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, picturebox

I just want to display the images based on selected row in datagridview which will display or fill in PictureBox1 ,and when click the other row another images will fill the box based on the images inserted to that other registered owners..MySql is my database

Here's my Code

```vb
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, _
           ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) _
           Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseClick
    cmd = New MySqlCommand("select ownpic from owners", con)
    Dim imageData As Byte() = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())
    If Not imageData Is Nothing Then
        Using ms As New MemoryStream(imageData, 0, imageData.Length)
            ms.Write(imageData, 0, imageData.Length)
            PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(ms, True)
        End Using
    End If


End Sub
```

Thank You..

Comment: ...and how is that code not doing what you want?

Comment: @Plutonix when I click the datagridview values cells there's nothing displayed in my Picturebox1..I just can't figure it out.I'm just a beginner...Thank you

Comment: @Plutonix Thank you so much

Comment: First step is to use the debugger since there is a condition test there: the code may be working perfectly but there is no image.  Set a breakpoint to see: a) if the code enters the method, b) does it get an image, c) is the image  valid.  Cell Click seems an odd event to choose - if they click somewhere to edit, your code will fire

Comment: Also, your SQL needs a WHERE clause if there will be more than one user in the DB.  Otherwise it should always get the image for the first record.  You ought not have to hit the DB at all.  If the DGV is bound to a DataTable, you could fetch the image from there on demand.